# Python Mechanize Value Error when opening a website

Tags: python, mechanize

when I try to open "twitter.com" with mechanize, it gives me a value error - too many packets to unpack.

```
br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1 )

br.addheaders = [ ( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" ) ]

br.open("https://twitter.com/signup/")
```

Is there any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-no, it's not about twitter specifically, it's just about the way you specified `addheaders` - *it is supposed to be a list of 2-item tuples* - first item in each of the tuple is a header name and the second - header value. In your case, it should be:

```
br.addheaders = [ ('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36" ) ]
```

([documentation reference](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers))